# How to pass basic credential(proxy credential) in selenium if username contains /

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium in client environment where proxy is set. Whenever i open chrome driver it ask for credentials. I can pass credential in below format
String baseurl= "https://username:password@abc.com/Security/Login.asp
But my username have '/' and it is not working
Username = 'account-01/d123456'

code :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",
Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./driver/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
//driver.manage().window().maximize();
String baseurl= "https://account-01/d123456:Rahul%456@abc.com/Security/Login.asp";
driver.get(baseurl);
```

Comment: you want your URL like this
https://account-01/d123456:Rahul%456@abc.com/Security/Login.asp ?

Comment: Yes, because username is  'account-01/d123456'

Comment: String Username = "account-01/d123456";
     String baseurl= "https://"+Username+":Rahul%456@abc.com/Security/Login.asp";

check this.

Comment: It is not working. After doing this i am getting below url in browser  "https://account-01/d123456:Rahul%456@abc.com/Security/Login.asp"

Comment: please share your expected output also.

Comment: whenever i am calling my page, it is asking for proxy credentials, i can pass in url, but there is / in username so it is not working

Comment: as in your username `/` is present its not allowed actually, Username must contains either Alphabets numbers or underscore Nothing else. in your case seems Invalid username